# Extract numeric values from a string for python

Tags: python, regex, replace, split

I have a string with contains numeric values which are inside quotes. I need to remove numeric values from these and also the `[` and `]`

sample string: `texts = ['13007807', '13007779']`

```
texts = ['13007807', '13007779'] 
texts.replace("'", "")
texts..strip("'")

print texts 

# this will return ['13007807', '13007779']
```

So what i need to extract from string is:

```
13007807
13007779
```

Comment: look like you need `int()`

Comment: Umm... does `numbers = [int(s) for s in texts]` do what you're after (given your sample)? Or is `texts` actually a string itself?

Comment: texts was a list i converted to a string  texts = str(re.findall(r"\d+", texts))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your texts variable is a string as I understood from your reply, then you can use Regular expressions:

```
import re
text = "['13007807', '13007779']"
regex=r"\['(\d+)', '(\d+)'\]"
values=re.search(regex, text)
if values:
    value1=int(values.group(1))
    value2=int(values.group(2))
```

output:

value1=13007807

value2=13007779

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*` unpack operator:

```
texts = ['13007807', '13007779']
print (*texts)
```

output:

```
13007807 13007779
```

if you have :

```
data = "['13007807', '13007779']"
print (*eval(data))
```

output:

```
13007807 13007779
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `map` and wrap around in `list`

```
list(map(int,texts))
```

Output

```
[13007807, 13007779]
```

If your input data is of format `data = "['13007807', '13007779']"` then

```
import re
data = "['13007807', '13007779']"
list(map(int, re.findall('(\d+)',data)))
```

or

```
list(map(int, eval(data)))
```